# Add a new entry with link in a table

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I bought the deitel java how to program book. I am following one of their exercises.
In my program I am connected to a mysql books database. I was able to add a new author, edit author, new title. However, part d) is confusing to me. Am I suppose to alter the table and add a foreign key?

Here are the exercises from the book so you can see part d)

```
a) Add a new Author
b) Edit the existing information for an author
c) Add a new title for an author (Remember that the book must have entry in the AuthorISBN table.)
d) Add a new entry in the authorISBN table to link authors with titles.
```

Here is a screen shot of the database open in "toad"

[image]

If they mean to write a sql statement would I add a new AuthorID with a reference to title?

```
ALTER TABLE AuthorISBN ADD FOREIGN KEY (AuthorID) REFERENCES title (AuthorID);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to alter the table. I assume they have given you the structure of the tables (the screenshot) and you are supposed to add new entries in all parts of the exercise. In d) they want you to add an entry to the table AuthorISBN, so that two entries in *Author* and *Title* are logically connected.

AuthorISBN consists of two data fields. AuthorID and ISBN are foreign keys, so for every entry in the table AuthorISBN there has to be an adequate entry with the same AuthorID in the table *Authors* and a an entry with the same ISBN in *Titles*.

So in a) you add an author. The AuthorID is automatically incremented, so you have to retrieve the ID after you inserted the author. In c) you add a book by this author. But how you know later, which author wrote a specific book? Or you want to retrieve a list of all book by an author. Thats why you add in d) an entry to AuthorISBN.

So with [JDBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/sql/package-summary.html) you would do something like this:

```
Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
String sql = "INSERT INTO AuthorISBN VALUES (" + authorID + ", '" + isbn + "')";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
```